# Как объединить Series если колонки имеют разные названия?

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Formula":['\tFormula A: UNIQUES(A)'] * 3, "level_number1": [1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Formula":['\tFormula B: UNIQUES(A)'] * 3, "level_number2": [4,5,6]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"Formula":['\tFormula C: UNIQUES(A)'] * 3, "level_number3": [7,8,9]})
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```

Нужно чтобы было 2 колонки `level number` и `Formula`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1**:

```
In [81]: (pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
            .set_index("Formula")
            .stack()
            .reset_index(name="level")
            .drop(columns="level_1"))
Out[81]:
                   Formula  level
0  \tFormula A: UNIQUES(A)    1.0
1  \tFormula A: UNIQUES(A)    2.0
2  \tFormula A: UNIQUES(A)    3.0
3  \tFormula B: UNIQUES(A)    4.0
4  \tFormula B: UNIQUES(A)    5.0
5  \tFormula B: UNIQUES(A)    6.0
6  \tFormula C: UNIQUES(A)    7.0
7  \tFormula C: UNIQUES(A)    8.0
8  \tFormula C: UNIQUES(A)    9.0
```

**Вариант 2**:

```
In [84]: pd.concat(map(lambda x: x.rename(columns=lambda c: re.sub("(level_number)\d+", r"\1", c)),  
                   [df1, df2, df3]))
Out[84]:
                   Formula  level_number
0  \tFormula A: UNIQUES(A)             1
1  \tFormula A: UNIQUES(A)             2
2  \tFormula A: UNIQUES(A)             3
0  \tFormula B: UNIQUES(A)             4
1  \tFormula B: UNIQUES(A)             5
2  \tFormula B: UNIQUES(A)             6
0  \tFormula C: UNIQUES(A)             7
1  \tFormula C: UNIQUES(A)             8
2  \tFormula C: UNIQUES(A)             9
```